# Paperclip - storing images

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am new to RoR paperclip gem and i have been trying out some examples on multiple image uploading and would like some info concerning this great gem.

In one example, i have an album model which allows user to upload multiple images. I noticed that the images are stored in public/system/datas and each image has its own folder labelled with the image_id. Is there a way of changing the way images are stored? For example, let's say i have one album with id '7' and this album has 3 images attached to it. Is it possible to store the images in a folder labelled with the album_id and inside that folder, i can find the subfolders containing my images??

Thanks a lot for any suggestion provided :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's well documented: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations

Comment: :) hey thank you so much, will have a look at this link, cheers

Comment: I finally managed to get right!! Used the interpolation method..Thanks a lot :)